# Cannot loop through an array of URLs I built to go to subpages for scraping using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I looked at **"Looping through a set of urls in Puppeteer"** and used that but I am still getting errors. I tried several different ways to do it based on different websites and this was the one that come closest to working.

When I run it, it opens the main page and then it opens the page from the first URL in the array. And then I get errors. I'm new to `puppeteer` and phone app development so I'm hoping its something small.

My code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');  // live webscraping

let scrape1 = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const page1 = await browser.newPage();
     let url =      'https://ws.petango.com/webservices/adoptablesearch/wsAdoptableAnimals2.aspx?species=Dog&sex=A&colnum=4&recAmount=75&detailsInPopup=Yes&authkey=rwtmnvh6fros1w6uad3t2btmh5tely62cf62s363tnsgoks4yu&css=https://www.tailshumanesociety.org/wp-content/themes/divi-child/iframe.css';  // link to page 

    await page.goto(url);
    var hrefs=[];
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let data = []; // Create an empty array that will store our data
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.list-animal-info-block'); // Select all Products

        var str1="https://ws.petango.com/webservices/adoptablesearch/";
        var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a'), hrefs = [];

        for (var i = 0; i<links.length; i++)
       {  
           var str2=links[i].href.slice(22,-3); 
           var wholepath=str1.concat(str2);
           hrefs.push(wholepath);
        }
        return hrefs
    });

    const urls = result;
    const idList = [];
    for (let i=0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const url = urls[i];
        await page1.goto(url);
        await page1.evaluate();
        const animalID = await page1.evaluate(() => document.getElementById("lblID").innerHTML);
        idList.push(animalID)
        browser.close()
    }
   browser.close()
   return idList
};

scrape1().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

The errors are :

> $ node d1.js
>   (node:10368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected to get |string| or |function| as the first argument, but got "undefined" instead.
>       at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:86:13)
>       at ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:48:23)
>       at ExecutionContext. (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
>       at DOMWorld.evaluate (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:112:20)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at Page.evaluate (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:782:43)
>       at Page. (/Users/wrlwnd/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
>       at scrape1 (/Users/wrlwnd/Desktop/d1.js:36:21)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:10368) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
>
> This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>   (node:10368) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

It also shows me this:

> **Do you want the application “Chromium.app” to accept incoming network connections?**

Deny or allow nothing happens.

I used the first part of the code to generate a list of URLs which point to popups for individual animals. That works. Then I try to loop through that list to open each page so I can scrape the information. The plan is to use `heroku` to provide an API type JSON input to the app. The individual animal pages are getting generated in real time and there is no API so this is making it tough! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see I have two evaluates. So I changed that. And it runs.

await page1.evaluate();
        const animalID = await page1.evaluate(() => document.getElementById("lblID").innerHTML);

I am still getting the "Do you want the application “Chromium.app” to accept incoming network connections?" message.